# ¿Cómo hacer un crud reutilizable en adonet C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un método registrar en C# pero me gustaría que fuese un método reutilizable, para simplemente llamar cada vez que lo necesite y pasar parámetros y no tener que escribir todo ese codigo cuando tenga que cambiar de entidad.

```
public Boolean insertar(string descripcion, string usuarioCrea)
        {
            cn = objCon.getConexion();
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_insert_TaBloque";


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombloque", descripcion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsuarioCreacion", usuarioCrea);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Y además para los demás métodos como actualizar,eliminar,buscarxId,listarxId

Comment: lo mejor seria hacer un CRUD en un store procedure y desde c# le mandas solo una palabra pro ejemplo insertaTabla1 y le pasas sus respectivos parametros, actualizaTabla1 y sus parametros...

Comment: Estoy haciendolo con store procedure

Comment: o usas un ORM (que ya tiene todo solucionado)... o escribis tu propio ORM...

Comment: existe alguna u otra forma de generar ese método reutilizable sin usar ORM.

Comment: No existe otra forma recomendable de hacerlo.